# Creation of nodes in VMs by using Kubernetes kubeadm and minikube

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create Kubernetes cluster with different number of nodes using same machine. Here I want to create separate VMs and need to create node in those VMs. I am currently exploring about kubeadm and minikube for these tasks.

When I am exploring I had the following confusions:

1. I need to create 4 number of nodes each need to create in different VMs. Can I use kubeadm for these requirement?
2. Also found that Minikube is using for creating the single node structure and also possible to use to creation of VMs. What is the difference between kubeadm and minikube ?
3. If I want to create nodes in different VMs which tool should use along with installation of Kubernetes cluster master?
4. If I am using VMs, then can I directly install VMware workstation / virtualbox in my Ubuntu 16.04 ?
5. In AWS EC2, they already giving the Ubuntu as a virtual machine. So is possible to install VMware workstation on ubuntu? Since it is VMs on another VM.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Kubeadm should be a good choice for you. It is quite easy to use by just following the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/). <strike>Minikube would give you only single node Kubernetes.</strike> As of minikube 1.10.1, it is possible to [use multi-node clusters](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/multi_node/).

1. Kubeadm is a tool to get Kubernetes up and running on already existing machine. It will basically configure and start all required Kubernetes components (for minimum viable cluster). Kubeadm is the right tool to bootstrap the Kubernetes cluster on your virtual machines. But you need to prepare the machines your self (install OS + required software, networking, ...). kubeadm will not do it for you.
2. Minikube is a tool which will allow you to start <strike>locally single node</strike> Kubernetes cluster. This is usually done in a VM - minikube supports VirtualBox KVM and others. It will start for you the virtual machine and take care of everything. But it will not do a 4 node cluster for you.
3. Kubeadm takes care of both. You first setup the master and then use kubeadm on the worker nodes to join the master.
4. When you use Kubeadm, it doesn't really care what do you use for the virtualization. You can choose whatever you want.
5. Why do you want to run virtual machines on top of your EC2 machine? Why not just create more (perhaps smaller) EC2 machines for the cluster? You can use this as an inspiration: https://github.com/scholzj/terraform-aws-kubernetes. There are also some more advanced tools for setting up the whole cluster such as (for example) [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/).

Comment: Ok Thank you for your response. I got your ideas including this Kops also. I am checking links related that you given to me. Here I only misunderstood is that, If I am  saying 4 nodes in separate Vms means, the Vms in the same machine as of the cluster master is not possible. Do I  need to launch 4 separate Ec2 for my 4 nodes as Vms ? Is this idea when we are saying nodes on different Vms? Can you clear this VM idea? I only started exploration about docker and kubernetes. I have lot of confusions. Can you please correct me sir about Vms idea please?

Comment: Kubernetes normally consist of one or more masters and one or more nodes. You are talking about 4 VMs ... I assume these would be 1 master + 3 nodes. Using VMs for this is ok for local development where you have one PC / server and want to run multinode cluster. You just setup 4 VMs running on your PC and install Kubernetes using Kubeadm.

But in AWS, the EC2 instances are already VMs. So in general there is no reason for you to get EC2 instance and create additional VMs on top of it. Just create more smaller EC2 instances and use them.

Comment: Ok..Now its very clear. Perfect. Thank you for your responses.