# Adding nodes to a Windows Minikube Kubernetes Installation - How?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have MiniKube running on my Windows 10 machine. I would like to add an additional node to the cluster.

1. I have a Centos VM running on a different host that has k8s installed. How to I get the `kubectrl join command` to run on the VM from the master node running on my Windows machine?
2. Do I need to install an overlay network on the MiniKube VM? Or is one already installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minikube is officially single-node at the moment. There's a discussion about this limitation at https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/94 But it seems people have [found ways to do it with VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706547/9705485) and there are other ways to run a [multi-node cluster locally](https://medium.com/devopslinks/deploying-multi-node-kubernetes-environment-in-your-local-machine-a66a1eb82e36). Otherwise I'd suggest creating a cluster with one of the cloud providers (e.g. [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/)).

Comment: Yep, but is there any way to JOIN a node to the Minikube master? I have another machine that has a Linux VM on it so all I need is the ability to join on to the master?

Comment: I think that is the same thing requested on https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1672 and that just points back to issue 94. So I believe it is not supported. I think this has also been touched on on SO before in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850342/creation-of-nodes-in-vms-by-using-kubernetes-kubeadm-and-minikube

Comment: However the answers are more nuanced on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687893/how-do-i-get-the-minikube-nodes-in-a-local-cluster I'll update my answer to reflect that