# How to migrate kubeconfig on windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, minikube

I have been trying to install minikube for two days now. I have run into issue after issue.  This one has me stumped.

- install minikube on windows 10
- Docker has been running with hyperv for months
- followed [windows](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/windows/) using choco  ignoring everything with hyperv install.

> W0107 08:23:27.485052    3337 common.go:77] your configuration file uses a deprecated API spec: "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1". Please use 'kubeadm config migrate --old-config old.yaml --new-config new.yaml', which will write the new, similar spec using a newer API version.

From what i understand there is a new config. that i need to migrate to.  to do that i need to use kubeadm but I haven't been able to find any information on where to find these files or how to do the migration.   Here is what i have tried.

From an elevated command prompt i ran:

- minikube ssh

Then i found kubeadm in the following directory.

- cd /var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.17.0

where by i started throwing some random commands at it in hopes of some help

```
$ ./kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:17:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


$ ./kubeadm config view
failed to load admin kubeconfig: open /home/docker/.kube/config: no such file or directory
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

$ ./kubeadm init --config defaults
unable to read config from "defaults" : open defaults: no such file or directory
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

As the error message said to run this i gave that a go.  That didnt work either

```
$ ./kubeadm config migrate --old-config old.yaml --new-config new.yaml
open old.yaml: no such file or directory
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

After digging around in the logs i found that it was trying to load the following config file so i tried to load that as the old one in hopes it was smart enough to make its own new one.

```
./kubeadm config migrate --old-config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml --new-config new.yaml
open /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml: permission denied 
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Ok then lets check the permissions on the file

```
$ ls -la /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1156 Jan  1  0001 /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
```

Well that's not good let's try to update it

```
$ chmod u=r /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml': Operation not 
 permitted
```

ok

```
$ sudu chmod u=r /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
-bash: sudu: command not found
```

## edit sudo

```
 $ sudo chmod u=r /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml 
 $ ls -la /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
 -r--r----- 1 root root 1156 Jan  1  0001 /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
```

## update 777

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
$ ls -la /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1156 Jan  1  0001 /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
fig new.yamlconfig migrate --old-config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml --new-conf
W0107 13:19:23.298409    4361 validation.go:28] Cannot validate kube-proxy config - no validator is available
W0107 13:19:23.298437    4361 validation.go:28] Cannot validate kubelet config - no validator is available
failed to write the new configuration to the file "new.yaml": open new.yaml: permission denied
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Still no dice. this appears to be a very limited bash shell.

## have a file

Ok thanks to some chmod 777's i know have a file but what do i do with it?

```
./kubeadm config migrate --old-config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml --new-config /home/docker/new.yaml
W0107 13:22:21.615314    6352 validation.go:28] Cannot validate kube-proxy config - no validator is available
W0107 13:22:21.615375    6352 validation.go:28] Cannot validate kubelet config - no validator is available
```

There seems to be little or no documentation on how to deal with this I have cross posted the issue on the forum. [#6227](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6227)   any help would be greatly appreciated.   I have tried to remove minikube and add it again with the same results.

## current status

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
ls -la /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml
cd /var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.17.0
./kubeadm config migrate --old-config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml --new-config /home/docker/new.yaml
sudo chmod 777 /var/tmp/minikube 
mv /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadmold.yaml
mv /home/docker/new.yaml /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml

minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --v=7 --alsologtostderr
```

No change same error message.

## 1.16.0

```
C:\Windows\system32>minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --kubernetes-version=1.16.0
* minikube v1.6.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Selecting 'hyperv' driver from user configuration (alternates: [])
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
! Unable to verify SSH connectivity: dial tcp: address fe80::215:5dff:fe37:c505:22: too many colons in address. Will retry...
! Unable to verify SSH connectivity: dial tcp: address fe80::215:5dff:fe37:c505:22: too many colons in address. Will retry...
! Unable to verify SSH connectivity: dial tcp: address fe80::215:5dff:fe37:c505:22: too many colons in address. Will retry...
! Unable to verify SSH connectivity: dial tcp: address fe80::215:5dff:fe37:c505:22: too many colons in address. Will retry...
! Unable to verify SSH connectivity: dial tcp: address fe80::215:5dff:fe37:c505:22: too many colons in address. Will retry...
! Unable to verify SSH connectivity: dial tcp: address fe80::215:5dff:fe37:c505:22: too many colons in address. Will retry...
X minikube is unable to connect to the VM: dial tcp: address fe80::215:5dff:fe37:c505:22: too many colons in address

This is likely due to one of two reasons:

- VPN or firewall interference
- hyperv network configuration issue

Suggested workarounds:

- Disable your local VPN or firewall software
- Configure your local VPN or firewall to allow access to fe80::215:5dff:fe37:c505
- Restart or reinstall hyperv
- Use an alternative --vm-driver
```

Comment: 1. You want to migrate kubeconfig from Linux Minikube to Windows Minikube? 2. Are you using Docker for Windows? 3. Did you installed `Minikube` based on this docs: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/windows/ ? 4. Did you usue Ubuntu / Debian / CentOS or something else? 5. You probably have typo `sudu` instead of `sudo`.

Comment: 1. i want to install minikube on windows 10.  2. yes i have been using docker for windows for a long time now.   3. yes followed exactly.  - everything to do with hyperv as its already installed.   4. no idea those are linux distros i am on windows 10.  5. check edit no dice with sudo

Comment: As per https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#deprecations-and-removals this apiVersion was removed in 1.17. Is it possible for you to run it on K8s 1.16 ?

Comment: @PjoterS this is my first time using k8s on my own i have no idea what you are asking.   I am just following the instructions.   I just want to get k8s running on my machine so that i can learn how to use it without having to pay for Google cloud time.    Isnt there a command that will install it and make it run?  sounds like you are saying it doesnt work at all on windows any more if you want me to go to an older version.   I did a pluralsight course that said to use minikube.

Comment: I mean to try install Kubernetes v.1.16 as v.1.17 was released on 9 Dec 2019 and some changes might be not included in course. I'm sure you can run Minikube on Windows. I will need to try it on Windows.

Comment: How exactly does one pick which version to install?  Doesnt the choco comand do that?   The link you posted is for windows.  Why wouldnt it run on windows?  are you saying its not supported for windows?

Comment: Link is from official documentation. `Minikube` version is not the same as `Kubernetes` version. You can choose kubernetes version during `minikube start` like
`$ minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --kubernetes-version=1.16.0`. However there are some differences between Linux and Windows. I am sure you can run minikube on Windows but I didnt do to it for a long time. I will need to test it. If you are in a hurry you can check https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6106

Comment: I saw issue 6106 and thought it might be related but it wasnt clear how to fix it.   So the issues is with Kubernetes and not with minikube check edit.  There is a different error with 1.16

Answer (score 1):

As you are able to see `kubeadm` version it suggest that you used Kubernetes [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/), which is bit different from `Minikube`.

**Kubeadm** is a tool to get Kubernetes working on existing machine. It will configure and start all required `Kubernetes` components. Using `Kubeadm` you are able to create cluster with multiple nodes (kubeadm join).

**Minikube** is a tool which start single `Kubernets Cluster` local node.

There is already good explanation in this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49850582/11148139) question.

I don't think that `Kubeadm configuration` from **Linux** will work on **Windows**. As you mentioned in comment, that you want to run `Minikube` in windows to learn Kubernetes, I will provide step by step how to run `Minikube` on Windows 10.

**Installation Minikube on Windows 10**

As you already have docker I will skip that installation steps.

**1. Download `kubectl` and `minikube`.**

Newest version is provided in [official kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows).

[kubectl v1.17](https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.17.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe) and [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases) from github (`minikube-windows-amd64.exe`).

**2. Add to `PATH` form folder to `Environment Variables`.**

Create folder where you will paste `kubectl.exe` and renamed `minikube.exe` file. 
Add This folder to `PATH`. (If someone would need [here is tutorial](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/)).

**3. Create external `Virtual Switch Manager` in `Hyper-V`.**

Go to `Hyper-V`. From the right menu choose `Virtual Switch Manager`. Choose `External` and name it `Primary Virtual Switch`. Then apply.

**4. Verify `minikube` and `kubeadm` versions.**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}​
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:12:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}​
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube version​
minikube version: v1.6.2​
commit: 54f28ac5d3a815d1196cd5d57d707439ee4bb392
```

**5. Create `Minikube Cluster`.**

Run `PowerShell` as Administrator.

`minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"`

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"
* minikube v1.6.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.17134 Build 17134​
* Selecting 'hyperv' driver from user configuration (alternates: [])​
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...​
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.17.0 on Docker '19.03.5' ...​
* Pulling images ...​
* Launching Kubernetes ...​
* Waiting for cluster to come online ...​
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"​
```

Now you can use `kubectl` commands and already have default resources required for running `Minikube`.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces​
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE​
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-c4cbj           1/1     Running   0          31m​
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-rqfth           1/1     Running   0          31m​
kube-system   etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          31m​
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube        1/1     Running   0          31m​
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          31m​
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          31m​
kube-system   kube-proxy-j6q29                   1/1     Running   0          31m​
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          31m​
kube-system   storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   0          31m
```

In addition, you can check [this](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c) article about running `Minikube` on windows.

Also you can consider [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) which will do many things automatically, however it will install older version of `kubernetes` (1.14 at the moment).

Comment: As an FYI to those in the future who come across this, `minikube start` will automatically create the v-switch for you, provided Hyper-V is installed. Though you do have to run the command with elevated privileges