# Launching Minikube as normal User on Windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, hyper-v, minikube

I'm trying to run minikube with hyperv without open an Administrator powershell. 
Is there any way?
I'm doing this:

```
choco install minikube
minikube.exe start --vm-driver "hyperv"
```

If I try to launch minikube start from a normal powershell it gives me this message:

```
X hyperv does not appear to be installed
```

Answer (score 4):

To launch minikube from non-admin powershell. You need to add a non-admin user to "Hyper-V Administrators" group.

Open PowerShell with administrator right. And run below command to add current user name to
"Hyper-V Administrators" group. You need to sign off and sign in to take effect.

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Hyper-V Administrators" -Member [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you didn't install `Hyper-V` or it wasn't installed properly due to Windows updates or some environment issues. You can check if `Hyper-V` works properly if you will execute `systeminfo`. More info in [Minikube docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/windows/). There are many ways to install `Hyper-V`. Easiest one is to install via `Turn Windows features on or off`, it's mentioned in [this](https://windowsreport.com/cant-install-hyper-v-windows-10/) article as `Solution 7`. If it wouldn't help you can try others.

After proper installation of `Hyper-V` you need to install [Docker for windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/), `Minikube` and `Kubectl`. I've already created mini tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59735469/11148139). You can also check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c) about `Minikube on Windows`. 
As additional information, I am not using admin rights.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So I should disable and enable again hyperv right? I've already install docker and minikube works if I launch it by an administrator powershell.

Comment: What you got when you execute `systeminfo` on your user?

Comment: ‘As additional information, I am not using admin rights.’
Can you please explain what you had to do to be able to start Minikube as a non-admin?

Answer (score 0):

Minikube works only with elevated rights on Windows
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6585#issuecomment-585269831