# "Hyper-v commands have to be run as an Administrator" in minikube when running as Administrator

Tags: powershell, windows-10, minikube

Windows 10 Enterprise. I'm trying to get minikube set up and am following the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/). When I try to confirm my installation, using the following command:

```
minikube start --driver=hyperv
```

Then I get this error:

```
X Exiting due to PR_HYPERV_AS_ADMIN: Failed to start host: creating host: create: precreate: Hyper-v commands have to be run as an Administrator
* Suggestion: Right-click the PowerShell icon and select Run as Administrator to open PowerShell in elevated mode.
* Documentation: https://rominirani.com/docker-machine-windows-10-hyper-v-troubleshooting-tips-367c1ea73c24
* Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4511
```

However, I *am* running Powershell as an Administrator. (Start menu > right click Powershell Icon > select "Run as Administrator".) I also tried running a regular cmd instance as Administrator -- same issue. Unfortunately the "Documentation" page in the message is a 404 and the "related issue" is closed with nothing useful.

How do I apply the appropriate Admin permissions to my Powershell or cmd instance to be able to use minikube with Hyper-V? [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60322537/launching-minikube-as-normal-user-on-windows-10) confirms that I do need to run as admin, but it appears that even running as admin isn't sufficient for whatever check minikube is doing under the covers.

<sub>(As a note, I was able to get it started using the docker driver, but I've done terrible things to my local docker and would prefer to use Hyper-V.)</sub>

- minikube v1.13.1

Comment: Have you tried to add your user to add your user to the Hyper-V Administrators group or run the shell in an elevated mode? See [here](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/minishift/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-driver-plugins.html#insufficient-privileges) for more details and remember to relog after making those changes.

Comment: Yes I ran powershell in elevated mode, which is why I asked the question since it was the recommended remedy and apparently made no difference.

Comment: Please try to add your user to the Hyper-V Administrators group or try with a different user with admin privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any future searchers, I ran into this same problem after an update to Windows 10.  I was also running Powershell as an Administrator, and still saw this error.

```
> minikube start --memory 3072 --cpus=2
* minikube v1.23.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19042 Build 19042
* Using the hyperv driver based on existing profile

X Exiting due to PROVIDER_HYPERV_NOT_RUNNING
```

> Please try to add your user to the Hyper-V Administrators group

This ^ was the fix for me.  Basically, I did the following:

- Right-clicked on "This PC" and selected "Manage."
- Found my user inside of "Local Users and Groups" -> "Users."
- Opened my user's properties.
- On the "Member Of" tab, I clicked "Add" and entered "hyper-v administrators."
- "Check Names" ensured that I had it spelled correctly.

After that, my `minikube start` worked as expected.