# Minikube "start" command is not creating vm or cluster(See Screen Shot)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to run`minikube start--vm - driver = virtualbox` or`minikube start--vm - driver = hyperv` by enabling the hyper - visor, but i am getting below error.
Can Someone please take me out of this:

[image]

Comment: Did you configure Hyper-V or Virtual box? Did you install docker or docker for windows? How about `--vm-driver=none` ? Please add information how you configured your Windows, Docker, Minikbue and Kubectl.

Comment: Does it directly dump this PNG file on to a console, or does it write out text logs?  Can you replace the image with the actual output of the command you're running?

Comment: I have minikube V1.9 and kubectl V1.8 in my system and also i has docker- desktop installed but it not in running state. when i ran "minikube version" and "kubectl version" cmd those are giving me same version that i mention here.

Not able to post commands output here but same happens with " minikube start --driver=hyperv" command as well. Same Output

Comment: You have quite old versions of Kubernetes and kubectl. I would suggest to update them. Second thing, did you follow any tutorials? I guess you didnt configure at all Hyper-V or VirtualBox. What if you will try configure this like in this tutorial: 
https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c

Answer (score 0):

For future, please try to post text instead of pic in your question. Second thing is that you are using quite old versions.

Usually errors like:

```
status error: host: state: machine does not exist minikube windows
The "minikube" host does not exist
```

are shown where you have some "leftovers" from previous `minikube` cluster.

It's hard to determine root cause exactly as it would need exact steps you have performed.

**1. Delete previous minikube and start again**

You have to use command like:

```
minikube delete
```

if you specified name of cluster using

```
minikube delete -p <your-cluster-name>
```

After that you should start minikube again.

```
minikube start --vm-driver=<depends-on-your-needs>
```

[Here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/) you have all `drivers` you can use with minikube.

**2. Use `--force` flag.**

It would look like:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --force
```

but it's also recommended to user `minikube delete` before this command.

**3. Steps to run Minikube on Windows.**

As you mentioned you already have docker, but if you would need to reinstall, you can find good tutorial on [Docker official docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/).

Good tutorial, how run `Minikube` on `Windows 10` can be found [here](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c).

You can also check [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59735469/11148139) for more updated version.

**4. Further issues with starting `minikube`**

If you will still have issues with running minikube, please update your question with debug logs. It can be found [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/debug/).

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyberv --v=7
```

or

```
minikube logs
```